# Power and rtn plane

Tags: pcb-layers

I have a simple board, +28v and +28v rtn, these will be planes, there are no signals. I was thinking simple, top and bottom layers, then I thought do the the planes need a plane to be between the two, which makes me think a 4 layer board. Basically my question is do I need a plane between my power and ground?

Comment: The thinnest prepreg allowed between Pwr&Gnd is best for noise decoupling if doing 4 layer.

Comment: Generally if a question is 'do I need a plane?', the answer is 'no'. Many commercially successful electronic products use single layer boards. There are specific reasons why a plane might be required on a board, but they don't tend to be ones that raise the question 'now do I need one or not?',

Answer (score 0):

You do not.  In fact, the closer together you place them, the more parasitic capacitance you create between them...although this capacitance will probably be too small to have any effect below ~1GHz, it is evenly distributed and low inductance.  Unless you're going to spend the extra money to put a layer in the stackup with a thickness of <5mil (<1/8mm) the effect would most likely be negligible...but in no case do the two planes have to be isolated from each other.

Comment: i did forget to add the board is to be .062 thk

Comment: thank you all for replying, I did boards 15 years ago, and now i have been thrown back in that drum, and having to re-educate, using different software, trying to remember packages and all the rules, so thank you! I am sure to post more questions in the future.